# Sharepoint Refinement Breadcrumb

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, breadcrumbs, refinements

As per Attached, How to create the refinement breadcrumb in SharePoint?

Please help me. Thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use jQuery to achieve it, the code below for your reference:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
    buildBreadcrumb();
    $("select[title='Department']").change(function(){
        buildBreadcrumb();
    });
    $("select[title='Branch']").change(function(){
        buildBreadcrumb();
    });
    $("select[title='Sub Branch']").change(function(){
        buildBreadcrumb();
    });
});
function buildBreadcrumb(){
    var department = $("select[title='Department']").val();
    var branch = $("select[title='Branch']").val();
    var subBranch = $("select[title='Sub Branch']").val();
    $("#refBreadcrumb").html(department+">>"+branch+">>"+subBranch);
}
</script>
<div id="refBreadcrumb"></div>
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for reply. The output is Undefined >> Undefined >> Undefined. In refinement, RefinableString05 = Department , RefinableString06 = Branch and RefinableString07 = Sub Branch. i'm already change the value. but still the same "Undefined" Please help me......

Comment: using IE F12 to check the select HTML code, or provide some image for further research.